# Bluebird long stack traces not working with node

Tags: javascript, bluebird

I've tried everything (in code, via env variables) to try to enable long stack traces with node and mocha, but having no luck.

```
global.Promise=require("bluebird");
Promise.config({
    longStackTraces: true
})

function sleep(ms = 0) {
    return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
}

async function testTraceInner() {
    await sleep(1)
    throw new Error("sup")
}

async function testTrace() {
    await sleep(1)
    try {
        await testTraceInner()
    } catch (e) {
        console.trace()
        throw e
    }
}

await testTrace()
```

I can only get this stack trace the below. Only anonymous instead of the long stack trace.

```
Trace
    at testTrace (seed.js:72:17)
    at <anonymous>
    1) "before all" hook
```

Comment: I can't test it right now but it should be `console.error(e.stack)`. The error object holds the long stack trace. `console.trace()` is not related to the error but reflects only the stack trace the js engine exposes.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior with either.